# How to find if FC-Switch using port-zoning or not Brocade FC 300

Tags: storage, storage-area-network, fibre-channel, brocade

I have to replace a HBA on RedHat5.3 due to card failure.

A tech guy asked me that "Check your FC-Switch Zoning Type of Port Zoning or not? , because if host accessed by WWNN, you'll need to update FC-switch config"

Is this below result on Brocade FC 300 showing Port-Zoning configuration or not?

```
fcsw03:admin> switchshow
switchName:     xxxxx
switchType:     71.2
switchState:    Online
switchMode:     Native
switchRole:     Principal
switchDomain:   1
switchId:       fffc01
switchWwn:      10:00xxxxxxxxxxxxx
zoning:         ON (zones)
switchBeacon:   OFF

Index Port Address Media Speed State     Proto
==============================================
  0   0   011700   id    N8   No_Light    FC
  1   1   011500   id    N8   Online      FC  F-Port 21:00:00:24:xxxxxxxxxxxx
  2   2   011300   id    N8   No_Light    FC
  3   3   011100   id    N8   No_Light    FC
  4   4   011600   id    N8   No_Light    FC
  5   5   011400   id    N8   No_Light    FC
  6   6   011200   id    N8   Online      FC  F-Port 50:06:01:60:xxxxxxxxxxxx
  7   7   011000   id    N8   Online      FC  F-Port 50:06:01:69:xxxxxxxxxxxx
  8   8   010f00   --    N8   No_Module   FC  (No POD License) Disabled
  9   9   010d00   --    N8   No_Module   FC  (No POD License) Disabled
 10  10   010b00   --    N8   No_Module   FC  (No POD License) Disabled
 11  11   010900   --    N8   No_Module   FC  (No POD License) Disabled
 12  12   010e00   --    N8   No_Module   FC  (No POD License) Disabled
 13  13   010c00   --    N8   No_Module   FC  (No POD License) Disabled
 14  14   010a00   --    N8   No_Module   FC  (No POD License) Disabled
 15  15   010800   --    N8   No_Module   FC  (No POD License) Disabled
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

use fabricos command `zoneshow`, which will give you the answer :

**wwpn zoning** : you have zonename with wwpn members (example : 21:00:00:24:xxxxxxxxxxxx ; 50:06:01:60:xxxxxxxxxxxx).

**port zoning** : you have zonename with each member like domain_id,port_id (example : 1,1 ; 1,6 is switchDomain 1 port 1 zoned with switchDomain 1 port 6)

PS : in case you have fancy names as zone members, you most probaly have aliases defined in the san switch. Use fabricos `alishow` to get the mapping between alias name and port/wwpn.